# Is there a simpler way to calculate correlation?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, correlation

> Let's consider that a variable y constructed from x
>
> $x_i ∈ \left\{1,3,5,7,8\right\}$
>
> $f(x_i)=2x_i+1$
>
> $y_i=f(x_i) + ε_i, ∀i∈ \left\{1;...;5\right\} $
>
> where $ε_i$ is a identically and independantly distributed random variable which follows a normal law $\mathcal{N(0,2)}$
>
> > calculate the correlation coefficient of $x$ and $y$. Is it still valid as an informer of dependance?

given $\sigma_{f(x)}$ which is about $5.66$ from the last exercise (which can be found again easily with a bit of calculation)

Let's try to find $σ_y$ from its formula:

$$σ_y=\sqrt[2]{Var(y)}$$

$$<=>σ_y=\sqrt[2]{\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^5 = (y_i-E(Y))²}{5}}$$

And that the expectetation $E(Y)$ of Y is

$$E(Y)={\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^5 = (y_i)}{5}}$$

Using $E(Y)=E(f(x_i))+E(ε_i)$?

then
$$=>E(Y)=E(f(x_i))$$

then
$$<=>σ_x=\sqrt[2]{\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^5 (f(x_i)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)})-E(Y))²}{5}}$$

But here I'm not sure to be going in the right direction... It give unbelievable complex calculation to cope with...

Comment: Are $x$ random or constants?

Comment: $x$ are random!

Comment: What is the probability structure on $x$?

Comment: "Let be x a variable taking the following values {1,3,5...}" By the way, I'm not a native, I'm not sure of what is a probability structure do you mean: If X follows a law? Then It doesn't. It's only a variable.

Comment: In your comment $x$ is called random. Then what is its distribution? Has every value $1,3,5,7,8$ equal chance to become the value taken by $x$ maybe? Finally: you use semicolons in your notation of a set. That is not custom, and confusing.

Comment: Your question, as of now, is absolutely meaningless. If you claim that $x$ are random, you should give me their probability structure. Otherwise, they would just be some data points. What about $Y$? You don't know the values of $Y$. This sort of looks like regression, but is somewhat very weird between regression and probability.

Comment: Yes it is regression, and actually it is custom in France and by the francophonie to use semicolons instead of "," which is used  for decimal numbers.

Comment: And maybe I get confused between random and variable. $x$ is a variable, but not a random variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Actually $\sigma^2_x=8$ so $\sigma_x \approx 2.83$.

It is $\sigma_{f(x)}$ which is about $5.66$.

You should then be able to calculate $\sigma^2_y$ (an integer) since it is $f(x)+\epsilon$, assuming the $x$ and $\epsilon$ are independent.  That gives you $\sigma_y$.

The covariance $\sigma_{f(x) y}$ is equal to the variance of $f(x)$, again assuming independence, and this is twice the covariance $\sigma_{xy}$, so you can easily calculate the correlation coefficient $\rho_{x y}= \dfrac{ \sigma_{x y} }{\sigma_x \sigma_y}$. This is a theoretical result informing you about the dependence of $y$ on $x$.

Comment: Actually I found from $\sigma^2_x=Var(x)=E(X²)-E(X)²$ =  (1+9/5+25/5+49/5+64/5)-(4.8)*(4.8) = 7,36.
Did I missed something?

Comment: @Marine1: Perhaps we are both making arithmetic mistakes. How did you get $5.66$ in the question?  Your expression should start "(1/5+..." rather than "(1+..." and this will change the variance you get. Meanwhile I had read $x_i \in\{1,3,5,7,9\}$ rather than your $x_i ∈ \left\{1;3;5;7;8\right\}$: making the change would give $\mu_x=4.8, \sigma^2_x=6.56, \sigma_x \approx 2.56, \sigma_{f(x)}\approx 5.12$.

Comment: Okay, maybe I should get rid of the French standard Math punctuation on MSE. ;) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226457/french-spacing-for-semicolon-in-math-mode
I agree with your first three values, I'm on my way to recalculate the last one $\sigma_{f(x)}$.

Comment: @Marine1: I do not mind your semi-colons and decimal commas (I wrote what I thought I saw, but copy-and-pasted what you wrote)

Comment: $σ_y^2=Var(f(x_i)+ε_i)$
<=> $σ_y^2=Var(f(x_i))+Var(ε_i)+2Cov(f(x_i),ε_i)?$
Then I calculate $Cov(f(x_i),ε_i)=E(f(x_i),ε_i)-E(f(x_i))-E(ε_i)$
Am I going in the good direction?